# setnames in data.table does result proper labeling of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have following results:

```
meanIndi<-c(5.73, 5.90, 5.71, 5.70, 5.57, 5.80, 5.87, 5.58, 5.54, 5.78, 5.72)

varianceI<-c(0.016, 0.017, 0.029, 0.022, 0.021, 0.050, 0.027, 0.024, 0.021, 0.016, 0.037)

precisionI<-c(62.319, 60.014, 34.861, 44.695, 47.599, 19.915, 36.760, 42.543, 47.259, 61.025, 27.343)
```

I create DataFrame as follows:

```
library(data.table)
combinedData<-as.data.frame(meanIndi)
combinedData$variance <-as.data.frame(varianceI)
combinedData$precision<-as.data.frame(precisionI)
combinedData$beta<-as.data.frame(round(combinedData$variance/combinedData$meanIndi, 4))


setnames(combinedData, old = c("meanIndi", "variance", "precision", "beta"),
  new= c("sampleMean", "sampleVariance", "samplePrecision", "beta"))
```

when I print `combinedData` I do not see the updated column names. I see column names as `meanIndi, varianceI, precisionI, varianceI`. How do I make it appear like `sampleMean, sampleVariance, samplePrecision, beta` ?

Comment: Your code is messy and you aren't working with a data.table, but a data.frame. For a data.table, the second line should be `combinedData <- as.data.table(meanIndi)`. To clean this a bit, you should do `combinedData$variance <- varianceI` with your third line and similar with the following lines.

Comment: actually, this helped, thanks @lmo. I have recently started using R and I always thought data.frame and data.table are same. pardon my ignorance

Comment: Also, you don't need to pass the vector `as.data.frame` to create a new column. Just pass  `combinedData$variance <- varianceI`.

Comment: No problem. A data.frame is a base R object. `data.table` is a (wonderful) user written package that extends the data.frame object. Also, using the preferred data.table syntax, that third line would be `combinedData[, variance := varianceI]`. You can read about this special data.table operator by typing `?":="` in the console.